# Search Azure-Blob-Storage files and fetch in mvc application in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

below code is for fetch data from blob json files and display on UI

code is taking too much time while traverse.

if blob path is this

```
myblob//mydata//1.json

myblob//mydata//2.json
```

I want to check like [{"name":"super"}]

if I found name = "super" in any one of the 1.json or 2.json I need to return that dataset.

```
var blobDirectory = container.GetDirectoryReference(directoryreference);
                IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> items = blobDirectory.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: false);

                string blobFilePath = String.Empty;
                foreach (var blob in items.OfType<CloudBlob>()

        .OrderByDescending(b => b.Properties.LastModified))
                {
                    string blobFileFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(blob.Name).Replace("\\", "/");
                    blobFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(blobFileFullPath).Replace("\\", "/");
                    if (blobFilePath != null)
                    { break; }

                }
  var blobFileDirectory = container.GetDirectoryReference(blobFilePath);
                IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> fileitems = blobFileDirectory.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: false);

                foreach (var fileitem in fileitems.OfType<CloudBlob>())
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob cbb = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileitem.Name);
                    var messageString = "";
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        cbb.DownloadToStream(stream);
                        string messageData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
                        messageData = messageData.TrimEnd();
                        if (!messageData.EndsWith("]"))
                        {
                            messageData = messageData + "]";
                        }
                        mymodel.BlobDeviceId = Session["name"].ToString();

                        JArray messageDataArray = JArray.Parse(messageData);
                        List<string> deviceCollection = new List<string>();
                        deviceCollection = Session["deviceCollection"] as List<string>;
                        foreach (var deviceId in deviceCollection)
                        {
                            foreach (JObject obj in messageDataArray.Children<JObject>())
                            {
                                if (obj["name"].ToString() == "super"
                                {

                                    messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
                                    jsonFormatted = JValue.Parse(messageString).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
                                    mymodel.BlobDeviceId = deviceId;
                                    goto outerloop;
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
            outerloop: if (jsonFormatted == "")
                {
                    jsonFormatted = "Currently data is not available";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return jsonFormatted;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this approach is right.  This will take time regardless.  I assume your json files would grow and it would take even longer. You need to index your json structure.  Azure search is very handy in this case. All you have to do is index your blob and use search api . you can find more about here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-semi-structured-data